# How can I do select * queries through map reduce in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I want to select all the columns of a document through "Map Reduce", but not able to understand how to write map function in this case.In short I want to do something like select * in SQL

Comment: @Manuel Don't troll, just vote to close if you think this is a "bad" question however, I personally think you may have misread the question if you think it is that simple and "bad".

Comment: Sometimes I'm not sure to vote for a close. He must have tried something, otherwise he wouldnt know that he didnt understand "how to write map function". He should show us what he tried, so we can help.

Comment: @Manuel Ok, well that line is normally used for a specific kind of trolling on this site, that's why I said that but if it is not then I take back what I said

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `.find()`. Example collection of `users`, `db.users.find()` would return everything.

Here's a nice list of SQL to MongoDB NoSQL commmands: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: Thanks tymeJV, but my question was related to "Map Reduce", I found a solution myself. we can use emit(this._id,this) in the map function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all the attributes you should probably emit `this`.

`emit(key, this);` in your map function.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `this` object, which represents your document in the map function, but it might be polluted by other properties, better to strip out the properties you need manually.

Comment: Reason for the downvote? It actually solved the OPs problem...